# What should I prepare for a Star Wars X-Wing tournament?

Tags: tournament, star-wars-x-wing

Next week I am participating in my first Star Wars X-Wing tournament. The tournament will be from 10am with up to 16 participants and three to four games. I have played Star Wars X-Wing with a friend for a couple of weeks now and collected a considerable amount of Empire ships. I have planned to bring the following things:

- Ships plus cards required for my build plus tokens
- Five printed copies of my build
- Bottled water and snacks
- Good mood

Additionally, I want to prepare the following things until the day of the tournament:

- Fly my build a few more times
- Read the FFG rules used at the tournament

Do you have any additional tips or did I forget anything?

Comment: Your list is pretty comprehensive. I usually take spare dice and rulers just in case there aren't enough, though I've never needed to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [current X-Wing Tournament Regulations](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/a9/af/a9af1e4a-41d1-4dee-8cc2-a5cedee684bf/x-wing_tournament_regulations_v121_text_version.pdf) (as of now, that's Version 1.2.1, effective November 1, 2016), you must have the following items:

- Ship models
- Bases
- Pegs
- Pilot cards (all from the same faction)
- Ship tokens (all from the same faction)
- Maneuver dials (matching your ships, but not necessarily from the same faction)
- Upgrade cards
- Tokens (other indicators are allowed with certain restrictions)
- A complete damage deck
- Sufficient dice for attack and defense rolls
- A full set of maneuver templates
- A range ruler
- A squad list (or arrive early to fill one out)
- Three unique obstacle tokens
- Any bomb tokens (in a reasonable quantity) required for your list
- ID tokens (or an equivalent way to distinguish your ships from each other and from your opponent's ships)

You should bring the following tokens not specifically listed above:

- Shield tokens *(unless your list only contains ships with no shields)*
- Focus tokens
- Evade tokens *(unless your ships do not have a way to get evade tokens)*
- Pairs of target lock tokens *(unless your ships do not have a way to acquire target locks)*
- Weapons disabled tokens *(if any of your ships can perform the SLAM action or if you want to indicate Corran Horn cannot perform attacks this round)*
- Stress tokens *(even if your ships have no red maneuvers on their dials)*
- Critical hit tokens *(many players do not worry about these, but it's a good idea―and good sportsmanship―to indicate which ships are affected by face-up damage cards)*
- Ion tokens *(players often only bring these when their is list capable of dealing ion tokens to enemy or friendly ships)*
- Tractor beam tokens *(like Ion tokens, usually only brought when their list is capable of dealing tractor beam tokens)*

---

You **cannot** use the following during a tournament round:

- Notes
- Third-party materials or information (reformatted versions of information available in official products are allowed)
- Third-party playmats not provided by the venue
- Third-party ship tokens
- Third-party obstacle tokens
- Third-party bomb tokens
- Third-party tokens or indicators that obscure significant component information, are not resistant to accidental modification, or do not have a purpose of use that is clear to both players
- Third-party or altered cards
- Non-identical or altered Damage card sleeves
- Third-party ship bases, or ship bases modified to alter their size or shape
- Custom "setup" templates designed to aid players in ship deployment
- Third-party ship models
- Ship models modified in a way that would create confusion about which ship the model represents
- Asteroids, debris fields, and bomb tokens altered in any way except marking to indicate ownership
- Third-party or altered dice (unobtrusive markings to indicate ownership are allowed)
- Movement templates or range rulers that do not match the dimensions of official maneuver templates, range rulers, or sections of an official range ruler
- Official products which are not yet legal (unreleased, or―for Premier events―not released 11 days before the event)

---

Refer to the following headings/subheadings of the tournament regulations for more information:

- Playmats
- Player Materials
- Squad Building
- Squad Lists
- Multiple Faction Ships
- Component Modifications
- Lost and Damaged Components
- Tokens
- Legal Products
- Game Setup (step 2)
- Taking Notes and Outside Material

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: So I finished my first tournament last Saturday (1:3 W:L, Place 9 out of 14). Here is my experience regarding the things I brought:

- Too much copies of the build, three are enough (one for the TO, one for the opposite player, one backup)
- More bottled water
- Pain killers (lack of oxygen after the third round got me head aches)
- Pen is always useful
- Marked my tokens on the evening before (there is some chaos on the table sometimes and I am sure I lost 1+ tokens regardless)

Additional things I should/could have brought:

- One guy broke his K-Wing, so next time I will bring glue to help out

One guy forgot his damage deck, but I think that would be too much to bring more than one for these cases (he played with an old damage deck from somebody else's collection).

Additionally, there is a good collection on tournament things on reddit:

- [Tournament Prep](https://www.reddit.com/r/XWingTMG/comments/3olg74/strategy_guide_tournament_prep/?st=is5vzf6o&sh=ee050eff)
- [Tournament Etiquette](https://www.reddit.com/r/XWingTMG/comments/4etubp/what_tournament_etiquetteprocedures_do_new/?st=is5vzhjq&sh=70345698)

Comment: You can't accept your own answer if you like, or another answer if you feel it better answers your question.